# Как пофиксить баг с постоянным респавном объектов в Enviro Spawn

Tags: c#, unity3d

Странный баг из за которого объекты при запуске игры начинают постоянно телепортироваться (респавниться) [видео](https://vk.com/video560618751_456239186)

```
using EnvSpawn;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ResourceHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int startHealth;
    public int health;
    public float destroyTime = 5f;
    private Transform resourceSpawer;
    public ItemScriptableObject resourceType;
    [SerializeField] private string spawnerName = "TreeSpawner";

    public void Start()
    {
        resourceSpawer = GameObject.Find(spawnerName).transform;
        resourceSpawer.GetComponent<EnviroSpawn_CS>().Generate();
        health = startHealth;
    }
    public void TreeFall()
    {
        gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Rigidbody rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rig.isKinematic = false;
        rig.useGravity = true;
        rig.mass = 200;
        rig.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationY;

        RespawnResource();
        Destroy(gameObject, destroyTime);
    }
    public void StoneGathered()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    public void RespawnResource()
    {
        float randomX = Random.Range(resourceSpawer.position.x - 
        resourceSpawer.GetComponent<EnviroSpawn_CS>().dimensions.x / 2, 
        resourceSpawer.position.x + resourceSpawer.GetComponent<EnviroSpawn_CS>().dimensions.x / 2);
        float randomY = Random.Range(resourceSpawer.position.z - 
        resourceSpawer.GetComponent<EnviroSpawn_CS>().dimensions.y / 2, resourceSpawer.position.z + resourceSpawer.GetComponent<EnviroSpawn_CS>().dimensions.y / 2);
        Vector3 rayPos = new Vector3(randomX, 100, randomY);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.SphereCast(rayPos, 6, Vector3.down, out hit, 200))
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.layer == 10)
            {
                GameObject newTree = Instantiate(gameObject, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
                Destroy(newTree.GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
                newTree.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
            }
            else
            {
                RespawnResource();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

и 2 код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GatherResources : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera mainCamera;
    public LayerMask layerMask;
    public InventoryManager inventoryManager;
    public ItemScriptableObject resource;
    public int resourceAmount;
    public GameObject hitFX;


    public void GatherResource()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2));
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1.5f, layerMask))
        {
            if(resource.name == hit.collider.GetComponent<ResourceHealth>().resourceType.name)
            {
                if (hit.collider.GetComponent<ResourceHealth>().health >= 1)
                {
                    Instantiate(hitFX, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
                    inventoryManager.AddItem(resource, resourceAmount);
                    hit.collider.GetComponent<ResourceHealth>().health--;
                    if (hit.collider.GetComponent<ResourceHealth>().health <= 0 && hit.collider.gameObject.layer == 9)
                    {
                        hit.collider.GetComponent<ResourceHealth>().TreeFall();
                        hit.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(mainCamera.transform.forward * 10, ForceMode.Impulse);
                    }
                    if (hit.collider.GetComponent<ResourceHealth>().health <= 0 && hit.collider.gameObject.layer == 11)
                    {
                        hit.collider.GetComponent<ResourceHealth>().StoneGathered();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение — просто удалить строчку:

```
resourceSpawer.GetComponent<EnviroSpawn_CS>().Generate();
```

которая находится в `void Start`